# Blue Prism: Read Windows' environment variables

Tags: blueprism

How do I access [Windows' environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/environment-variables) using Blue Prism?

I specifically need to get the value of `%TEMP%`, as I wish to use that value in a file saving action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a feature that is (strangely) missing from BP. The only similar function native to Blue Prism is `Get Special Folder Path` in `Utility - File Management` that, however, returns only folders in [Environment.SpecialFolders Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2), which doesn't contain temp.

I usually write an extension to that VBO with a single VB.NET one liner:

```
tmpFolder = Path.GetTempPath()
```

Which returns:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a new BP object (C#), and add this line to the code stage,
set `name` as input and `value` as output.

```cs
value = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(name);
```

This will return environment variable